# Visual Basic 6 add to textbox very long text

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have a textbox and a button and I need when I press a button text to appear on textbox.

But! The text is about 8000 char and max I can put inside quotes is like 1000

Here is example:

```
textbox.text = "Very long text"
```

Comment: Is it visual basic 6 like in the title or C#?

Comment: [TextBox Control for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z8k5by%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: its visual basic 6

Comment: Is this a limit you experience in the IDE?

Comment: Textbox controls give up when the amount of text is larger than can be scrolled.  Which is 32767 *pixels*, an internal OS restriction.  Which is always larger than the amount of patience a user has when trying to read the text.  Just don't create an unusable user interface and you don't have a problem.  Large amounts of text should be displayed in a multiline textbox that can be scrolled vertically or should be abbreviated with ellipsis if the actual text is irrelevant.

Comment: i have a multiline textbox, it just dont allow me to put more than 100 chars

Comment: Then you are simply doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try out setting up parameter [MaxLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x78eke3d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
textbox.MaxLength = 8000
```

Comment: dont quite understand where to put this

Comment: @WooLf before your `textbox.Text = "very long text"` and without the ;

Answer (score 0):

Change it in the properties window. Click on the textbox and scroll down until you see MaxLength. When you find it, change it to 8000

Answer (score 0):

From Help *Code Limitations*

> The amount of code that can be loaded into a form, class, or standard module is limited to 65,534 lines. A single line of code can consist of up to 1023 bytes. Up to 256 blank spaces can precede the actual text on a single line, and no more than twenty-four line-continuation characters ( _) can be included in a single logical line.

Answer (score -1):

You could build up your textbox text with multiple shorter statements as well.  For example:

```
textbox.Text = "My first section of text"
textbox.Text = textbox.Text & "My second section of text"
textbox.Text = textbox.Text & "My third section of text"
```

Alternatively, take a look at the RichTextBox.  It uses an append method (and gives you a lot more formatting options):

```
myrtb.append "My first section of text"
myrtb.append "My second section of text"
myrtb.append "My third section of text"
```

Comment: VB6 RichTextBox doesn't seem to have an append method. Perhaps in VB.net.